# Operand should contain only 1 column Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query to fetch multiple column values based on the condition specified in the case statement and encountered the following error operand should contain only 1 column mysql query.I just can't figure out what the problem is.Is there a simple fix to this, or another way to write my query?

```
SELECT id,
          CASE 
             WHEN id='' THEN (select * where name='abc')
             ELSE (select * from sample)
          END
    FROM sample WHERE name='abc' and status='xyz'
```

Comment: you probably need a join? but it's not clear, you should explain better how your sample table is structured and what you are trying to accomplish..

Comment: @fthiella: I have a table with three columns id, name and status. Following is the requirement. Scenario 1: querying id based on two filters name and status and fetching id,name and status if matched the condition and id is not empty. Secenario 2: If ID is empty in scenario 1 then querying id only based on applying one filter which is name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a union query that combines three different queries:

```
select * from samples
where name='abc' and status='xyz'

union all

select * from samples
where
  name='abc' and not exists (
    select * from samples
    where name='abc' and status='xyz'
  )

union all

select * from samples
where
  not exists (
    select * from samples
    where name='abc'
  )
```

- the first part will return all records from samples that match the name and status condition
- the second part will return all records from sample that match the name condition, but only if the first query doesn't return anything
- the thirds part will return all records from sample whenever both the first and second query don't return anything

(those three queries can be combined together with ORs but the union query is easier to read and clearer)

Comment: Thanks @fthiella but my third query is not returning any values. My criteria should be if the first part fails to return any values then I need to fetch the id and other columns based on applying the filter only on name.

Comment: @user2401547 please see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcb6c1/1 where I run the same query three times. 1. there's a match, only (abc,xyz) will be returned 2. there's no match, all (abc) will be returned 3. no match, all rows returned